# Removing Animation from Wpf Checkbox

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, windows-7-x64

I have an enormous (5000+ items) TreeView that displays a series of nested checkboxes. When a parent checkbox is checked all of the children also become checked. I'm profiled the logic, and the click propagation occurs basically instantly but the rendering takes several seconds.

I've narrowed it down to the animation that the BulletDecorator does on the click animation.

I want to basically modify the behavior of the checkbox to have zero animation. How do I do this? I'm thinking of inheriting from CheckBox and adding a "AnimationEnabled" DependencyProperty that toggles the animation of the BulletDecorator.

I've found this link, but I have no idea how to actually modify the behavior or redefine a BulletDecorator:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752319(v=vs.85).aspx

How to I modify the animation behavior of the standard Wpf Checkbox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open Blend
2. Create a new project
3. Add a Check box
4. Right click on it "Edit copy of the style"
5. Go into XAML
6. Remove the bullet decorator in question
7. Copy all XAML enclosed in `<X.Resources>...</X.Resources>`
8. Paste the XAML you just copied in the

`<Root.Resources>...</Root.Resources>`

Example:

`<Grid.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="MyCheckBoxStyle" TargetType="{x:Type CheckBox}">
        ...
    </Style>
</Grid.Resources>`

9. In the HierarchicalDataTemplate of your tree, you should apply the style to the Check box